# Area Solar Radiation tool in ArcGIS - Outputs for all time intervals vs One Output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, solar-radiation

I aim to create output (solar map) every 15 minutes for the whole day and because I am not quite sure how it works, I wanted to validate the sum of radiation: I have created first output with 0.25h interval for each interval and second one with same hour interval (0.25h), but with unchecked "Create outputs for each interval" option. Rest of the options are set in the same way for both cases.

I am a little bit confused because total sum of radiation differs for the outputs (as on the picture):
[image: Outputs of the Area Solar Radiation tool]

What am I doing wrong?

I assume it is too big difference to skip it. Maybe the way I am calculating it is not correct.

Is it possible to have such outputs?